# PC won't post after replacing mobo

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I am trying to fix an older HP desktop (~2 yrs old) that didn't seem to have video working. The video card on the machine was integrated. After some debugging, it looked to be the mobo, so I went out and got a new one (also with integrated video). Now, it pretty much does the same thing.

Here's the symptoms: no video, doesn't post at all, fans DO spin (both chasis and CPU).

Any other ideas? I suppose it could be the CPU, but I would think if it was, it would at least post.

Comment: Have you tried a different monitor?

Comment: I actually got it to boot by switching out the CPU, but now I'm getting a BSOD of 7xB. Could it still be one of the components?

Answer (score 1):

Have you plugged in both power connectors?

There's two - the long block which powers the various expansion ports and a 2x2 block which powers the CPU.

This caught me out when I had to replace my motherboard recently.

Comment: Yeah. I plugged in both (after having to re-seat the smaller 4-pin power several times). Computer boots, just doesn't POST.

Comment: @Dan - I had to ask :)